# Update Button text after Button click

Tags: java, android, xml, button

I want to update the text in a clickable button after I click it.

I have a button for liking a product, its text shows how many likes the product has.

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/like"
 android:text= "@string/like"
 android:drawableTop="@drawable/like"/>
```

`<string name="like">Likes:  </string>`

So in my `onClick()` method for this button I use `like.setText("Likes: " + product.getLikes());` in order to update the text:

`Button like = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.like);`

```
like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                like(product);
                like.setText("Likes: " + product.getLikes());
            }
        });
```

The `like()` method does work - I checked that. The method `product.getLikes()` returns the correct value.
However the button stays the same. I can´t figure out what the issue is.

UPDATE:
I noticed the text updates itself once i scroll down to other items and up again....

Comment: Could you please share more code (like your onClick method)

Comment: You want to update TextView and you are calling reference to button. Your code shows your button name is "like" and you are calling setText() for that object ? Please post whole code also name of your text view.

Comment: Instead of "like.setText(...)" use this: " ((Button)v).setText(...)" This way you can at least make sure you are updating the clicked View.

Comment: You can try to debug it at that exact same line, I cannot think of a reason other than getLikes() returning incorrect value or some other view getting updated (in that case try to use variable v parameter of onClick() to set text)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String mlikes= product.getLikes().toString();
like.setText("Likes: " + mlikes);`
```

Comment: I already tried that.
The thing is, when I first open the fragment with product in my app it shows the number of likes how it should, only when I want to add a like by clicking the button, it doesn´t update it.

Comment: use TextView instead of Button

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            btn.setText("new text");
        }
};


btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  }
});
```

Comment: I like Handlers. But please explain to me: Why do I have to go to the post office and send a letter to my own home to tell the reader (=me) to turn the lights off if I can just as well simply turn the lights off? Or in this case: if my switch seems to be broken, what would be improved by writing a message?

Comment: the handler works for a different problem in a fragment - thanks for that
But for this problem it doesn´t do anything.
However I noticed that it updates itself when i scroll down and up again...